# php artisan serve ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED after update to laravel 8

Tags: laravel, localhost

On my Mac High Sierra:

- I have updated PHP from 7.1 to 7.3
- I have updated Laravel from 5 to 8

and everything seems fine.

When I run `php artisan serve` I get this message:

```
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

When I open the url I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in the browser.

The terminal gets an update with this message everytime I reopen the url:

```
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8001
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8002
```

I have tried the following solutions:

- restart my mac;
- flush dns;
- MAMP is closed;
- `php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1` not works;
- composer is updated;
- php.ini is set in folder `/opt/local/etc/php73` with `variables_order = "GPCS"`

What's is wrong with these solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Install Laravel 9 and php 8

Answer (score 0):

why would you update to laravel 8 when there’s laravel 9 in the first place

Comment: You are right but I have a tutorial about laravel 8 and I'm working with php 7 usually.